Where is antineutrino in standard model Lagrangian?
I'm somewhat confused by the content I studied in Srednicki's work, where the neutrino is described as a Majorana field. In this framework, there shouldn't technically be antineutrinos, given the nature of Majorana particles. A possible refinement might be to assign different lepton numbers to left-handed and right-handed neutrinos, although I don't see why lepton number conservation is necessary. Could there be gaps in my understanding?
